# svn conflict pointing to empty dir/file

Tags: svn, tree-conflict

I destroyed my subversion tree, and I don't know what could have caused it. I used `svn ignore` on some files a while ago, but as the project is being revisited, I decided to retract the `svn ignore` by using `svn propdel svn:ignore -R`. This removes all ingnores I've made, but I didn't think that would be a problem.

However, when I now try to update, I get the following message:

`Conflict for property 'svn:ignore' discovered on ''.`

What does the empty single quotes mean? Also, subversion seems to have trouble finding my working directory, as I'm getting `!M      .` at the top of the output when I run svn up. Finally, what doesn't make sense to me is how does svn accurately display what files I've modified if it can't find my directory? (Maybe I'm misinterpreting the `!M` message, doesn't that mean that the path is missing?)

Comment: not sure why the empty quotes, but a quick fix is to delete everything and check out a new working copy.  If you have existing changes then checkout into a new directory and copy your existing changes over to the new working copy. This doesn't actually answer your question, that's why it's a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I may have to simply end up doing as you say. I've made quite a few edits to several files; I was hoping to revert just the global ignore command, but that doesn't seem to be doable, as subversion is now having trouble with the whole dir...